# Cannot mount XFS volume on Hetzner vps

Tags: mount, xfs, hetzner

After a volume a resizing i cannot mount an attached volume on Hetzner cloud vps

```
root@MONITOR-BACKUP /mnt # mount -o discard,defaults /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0HC_Volume_1552045 /mnt/BACKUP-STORAGE
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
```

fdisk -l

```
root@MONITOR-BACKUP /mnt # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 19.1 GiB, 20480786432 bytes, 40001536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x44c5162c

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 40001502 39999455 19.1G 83 Linux
```

dmesg

```
[ 1139.220976] XFS (sdb): xfs_inactive_ifree: xfs_ifree returned error -117
[ 1139.223771] XFS (sdb): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 1853 of file /build/linux-xZ5nrU/linux-4.9.210/fs/xfs/xfs_inode.c.  Return address = 0xffffffffc0819e5b
[ 1139.229393] XFS (sdb): I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
[ 1139.231934] XFS (sdb): Please umount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
[ 1139.234544] XFS (sdb): Ending recovery (logdev: internal)
[ 1139.236972] XFS (sdb): Error -5 reserving per-AG metadata reserve pool.
[ 1139.239324] XFS (sdb): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x8) called from line 1038 of file /build/linux-xZ5nrU/linux-4.9.210/fs/xfs/xfs_fsops.c.  Return address = 0xffffffffc080bb87
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a filesystem on that drive? It wasn't even partitioned!

Comment: it's a 2 year working volume where I manage backups. 
yesterday i realized it was full, i did a resize and resize2fs

Comment: If you solved this yourself, you should post an answer below. Solutions do not belong in the question here.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED USING**

```
xfs_repair /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-0HC_Volume_1552045
```